# Iperf UDP listening on used port

Tags: port, asterisk, sip, iperf

I get  WARNING[9157] chan_sip.c: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission  error on asterisk and trying to troubleshoot the problem.

Now asterisk is listening on 5060 port:

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10766               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10767               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                               2203/perl
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18970               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18971               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16562               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16563               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14400               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14401               0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060                0.0.0.0:*                               48991/asterisk

Now if I do :

```
[root@tekium ~]# iperf -s -u -i 1 -p 5060
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5060
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  122 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local [ip removed] port 5060 connected with [ip removed] port 5060
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   0.000 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   740 Bytes  5.92 Kbits/sec   0.000 ms 1229870664/1229870665 (1e+02%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   740 Bytes  5.92 Kbits/sec  62.560 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec   740 Bytes  5.92 Kbits/sec  121.212 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
[  4] local [ip removed] port 5060 connected with [ip removed] port 25910
[  5] local [ip removed] port 5060 connected with [ip removed] port 61443
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec   331 Bytes  2.65 Kbits/sec  15699968176.192 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  15699968176.192 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  15699968176.192 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
[  5]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.20 KBytes  9.81 Kbits/sec   0.000 ms 1229870664/1229870665 (1e+02%)
[  5]  1.0- 2.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   0.000 ms    0/    0 (-nan%)
```

So if asterisk listening on port 5060, how iperf receives these messages?

Does this makes sense?

Update:

```
 netstat -su 
IcmpMsg:
    InType3: 17
    InType8: 40
    OutType0: 40
    OutType3: 1016
Udp:
    477 packets received
    1072 packets to unknown port received.
    51242 packet receive errors
    728 packets sent
```

I tested with iperf udp traffic, 0% loss, so how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how more specific binds work to allow two applications to bind to the same UDP port? Or are you asking how to troubleshoot a problem with Asterisk? If you want help with a problem, you need to describe the problem to us. All you've done is state one symptom.

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem, by making kernel network buffers bigger